# PostGIS Elevation Query

Tags: postgresql, postgis, elevation

I have a situation where i need to find the elevation of a givin location identified by LAT and LON, i am already aware of [Google's elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation), and i am also aware of [earth-tools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#height) web services, what i really want is a link or an example query where i can send LAT and LON to a postgresql database and get an elevation value as a response, is this is doable by PostGIS? if yes then well you please shed some light on it.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess that it depends on your data. I suggest you to upload some 3d layer to PostGIS. After that try this approach: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42971/21423

Comment: Thanks for our reply, but i don't really see how this is relevant to the issue, as a matter of fact am seeking a way to lockup elevation for a particular location identified by its longitude and latitude rather than converting geography points to GPS.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash: you can't lookup data in the database that you didn't store in the database.

Comment: I ended up using "gdal" to do this without the need for postgis or even postgresql, an example for this would be:

{gdallocationinfo -valonly -geoloc SRT.tif 35.4954490661621 51.5574703216553}

Note that you need to install "gdal-bin" in order to get this command active in your box, just fire:
{apt-get install gdal-bin} (Or if you got something other package manager than Debian or Debian based distros)

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've already seen this snippet [here](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html).

Assuming that you have the valid raster layer inside your PostGIS:

```
-- get raster values at particular postgis geometry points
-- the srid of your geometry should be same as for your raster
SELECT rid, ST_Value(rast, foo.pt_geom) As b1pval, ST_Value(rast, 2, foo.pt_geom) As b2pval
FROM dummy_rast CROSS JOIN (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(3427927.77, 5793243.76), 0) As pt_geom) As foo
WHERE rid=2;

 rid | b1pval | b2pval
-----+--------+--------
   2 |    252 |     79
```